# Thunderbird only keeps messages of main folder on server with IMAP account?

Tags: thunderbird, imap

I just tried out the latest Thunderbird with an IMAP account and found that only the messages that are not moved into subfolders by rules stay on the server. This makes the most important feature of the IMAP protocol senseless (keep messages on the server until the are marked as deleted in a client which allows them to be received on different devices without a time limit). Is there a setting to avoid this behavior in Thunderbird or is this a server setting problem?

Comment: In the Account Settings dialog (Tools > Account Settings...Edit > Account Settings...), have you checked "Keep messages for this account on this computer"?

Comment: Yes, I have this checked.

Comment: Note, the setting  "Keep messages for this account on this computer"  is only related to whether Thunderbird will proactively CACHE emails from the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually all messages in the sub-folders were on the Dovecot server, the sub-folders are just hidden in the Linux file system with a dot at the beginning of the folder name. In iPhones you must correctly set the IMAP Path Prefix (in iOS 12.1.3 under Passwords & Accounts -> [Your IMAP Account] -> Account -> Advanced -> IMAP Path Prefix). If you don't know your prefix, try "INBOX" or leave it completely blank. The folders should now be displayed. If not, ask your server admin for the correct prefix value.